# SQLAlchemy ORM - how to represent n to n relationship between a view and another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I use postgresql and sqlalchemy 2

I have one materialized view and two tables.

The materialized view is an union of two tables with the same "shape"

Here is the materialized view in pseudocode

```
table1(id, name, surname)
table2(id, name, surname)

materialized_view as
select 
  'T1' AS source,
  *
from table1
UNION
select
  'T2' AS source,
  *
from table2
```

I also have two other table holding tags associated to either table1 or table2 rows

in pseudocode

```
tags(id, name)
tags_association(
  id,
  fk_tag fk to tags.id,
  fk_table1 fk to table1.id nullable,
  fk_table2 fk to table2.id nullable
)
-- tags_association have a constraint being xor fk_table1 fk_table2 (an association have either reference to table1 or table2, not both, not none)
```

I use sqlalchemy orm to represent the `materialized_view` in my application.

```
class Table1(db.Model):
   ...
class Table2(db.Model):
   ...
class Tags(db.Model):
   ...
class TagsAssociation(db.Model):
   ...

class MaterializedView(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = "materialized_view"
    
    source = Column(String)
    id = Column(Integer)
    
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(Integer)
```

I'm able to perform query with my `MaterializedView` class. However, I'd like sqlalchemy to perform the necessary joins to retrieve associated tags with rows.

In pseudocode

```
class MaterializedView(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = "materialized_view"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(Integer)

    tags = relationship(
      "Tags",
      ... # tell sqlalchemy how to perform the join
    )
```